# HTTP 400 When Trying to Send HTTP Post GraphQL Query using HttpClient in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, apache-httpclient-4.x, graphql-java

Have a post query for an external GraphQL server which works in Postman Pro setup as a Pre-request Script.

Am trying to hit an external GraphQL server using HttpClient.

Maven dependencies pom.xml:

```
<!-- Apache Commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Google Code -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Hardcoded the pre-request script as follows:

GetDataAsRequest.java

```
public class GetDataAsRequest {
    private static final String GET_DATA_REQUEST_TEMPLATE = 
    "query {" 
        + "    viewer {     "
        + "        data(id: \"10045701-2017-41a4-33f4-bf8481cf01dc\") {" + 
        "            id"
        + "            createdDate" 
        + "            lastModifiedDate" 
        + "            abbreviation"
        + "            cityStateRegion" 
        + "        }"
        + "    }"
        + "}";
    }

    public static String generateQuery() {
        return String.format(GET_DATA_REQUEST_TEMPLATE);
    }
}
```

MyController:

```
public class MyController {

    private static final String EXTERNAL_API_URL = "https://sample-api.com"

    public static void main (String args []) {

        // Generate Access Token
        String accessToken = OAuth2Client.generateAccessToken();
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(EXTERNAL_API_URL);
        StringEntity postBody = new StringEntity(GetDataAsRequest.generateQuery());
        postBody.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        postRequest.setEntity(postBody);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Although the same OAuthToken and HTTP post query works when I copy it from stdin (console) into a Postman call, I keep getting an HTTP 400 when trying to emulate the same call using HttpClient inside a Java program:

```
03:25:30.690 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {s}->https://https://sample-api.com
03:25:30.751 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to https://sample-api.com:443
03:25:30.943 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
03:25:30.950 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
03:25:30.950 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
03:25:30.951 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
03:25:30.951 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
03:25:30.951 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: POST /v1/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
03:25:30.951 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "POST /v1/oauth/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Content-Length: 119[\r][\n]"
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Host: https://sample-api.com[\r][\n]"
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "[\r][\n]"
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> POST /v1/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 119
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: https://sample-api.com
03:25:30.952 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
03:25:30.953 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.5)
03:25:30.953 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=fghuXeULFBdW4B1dmRY0MhROMRQnlumk&client_secret=MM2banXEq2R1GhRvIQ2d2AKRx0SORvb4"
03:25:31.132 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.134 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "X-Application-Context: application:prod[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.134 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.134 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Cache-Control: no-store[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.134 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.134 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Accept-Ranges: bytes[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "X-Cache-Hits: 0[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "X-Timer: S1525774921.421988,VS0,VE41[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 10:22:01 GMT[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Content-Length: 325[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "X-Sample-APP: sso[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,POST,OPTIONS,GET,PATCH,DELETE[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "[\r][\n]"
03:25:31.136 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
03:25:31.136 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
03:25:31.136 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << X-Application-Context: application:prod
03:25:31.136 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Type: application/json
03:25:31.136 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Cache-Control: no-store
03:25:31.136 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Pragma: no-cache
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Accept-Ranges: bytes
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << X-Served-By: cache-sample-las9320
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << X-Cache-Hits: 0
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << X-Timer: S1525774921.421988,VS0,VE41
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 10:22:01 GMT
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Length: 325
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Connection: keep-alive
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << X-Sample-APP: sso
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,POST,OPTIONS,GET,PATCH,DELETE
03:25:31.138 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
03:25:31.141 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
03:25:31.147 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "{"access_token":"fkMmGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6bnVsbCwiZGV2aWNlSWQiOm51bGwsImNsaWVudElkIjoiaUxIdVhlVUxGQmRXNEIxZG1SWTBNaFJPTVJRbmxmZUsiLCJhZElkIjpudWxsLCJleHAiOjE1MjU3Nzg1MjEsImlhdCI6MTUyNTc3NDkyMX0.U3gacgf7a8hlwCuCn6yGXc0z6E5Zrwgii3B_77xFlyo","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":null,"scope":null}"
03:25:31.147 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@2ddc8ecb
03:25:31.147 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
```

Is this returning an HTTP 400 because my request body is wrong in some way?

Is there an easier way to obtain JSON responses via GraphQL's Java libs:

```
<!-- GraphQL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

A lot of examples on the Internet show how to setup and external GraphQL server, what I need is to learn how to use the GraphQL Java libs serving as a client library to parse and obtain the right GraphQL response from an external server...

This is returning correctly from Postman Pro and curl but not using HttpClient.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the server? If so, why not put a break point there and inspect what fails? If you don't control the server, I'd say double-check the differences between what you send here and with Postman.

One thing looks very suspicious immediately. You're sending a POST that claims to have a JSON body, but the string you're sending is a raw GraphQL query and not JSON at all.

I could tell you to turn the request body into a JSON object as defined by the [GraphQL over HTTP Spec](http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/), but without knowing if your server actually implements this spec, it is just a guess.

What the spec defines as a proper body of a POST request is a JSON object with 3 fields: `query`, `operationName` and `variables`. The `query` field should contain the query **string** (so stringify the query first), `operationName` contains the name of the operation to execute in case there's multiple (not relevant to your case), and `variables` contains a JSON object with variables as key-value pairs (not relevant right now).

Meaning in your case, the body should look like:

```
{
    query: "{
        viewer {
            data(id: \"10045701-2017-41a4-33f4-bf8481cf01dc\") {
                id
                createdDate
                lastModifiedDate
                abbreviation
                cityStateRegion
            }
        }
    }"
}
```

To put this string into Java code, all this needs *an extra level of escaping* but I hope your IDE will take care of that. Also notice the line breaks are important. If you lose them for any reason, you must put commas between the selected fields for the query to remain valid.